# pst-text broken?

Tags: xetex, luatex, pstricks

```
% Lua- or XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-grad, pst-text}

\begin{document}

\psset{fillstyle=gradient,gradbegin=red,gradend=cyan}
\pscharpath[gradangle=90]{\huge\bfseries TEST}% appears in black

\end{document}
```

Look at the MWE. The word "TEST" should appear in a color gradient, but it is black.

What is wrong here? (The same result in Plain Lua- and XeTeX.)

Comment: Note that it does work with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` as compile sequence. Maybe this was some functionality that was never implemented by the PSTricks handling in XeTeX/LuaTeX?

Answer (score 3):

That is the only package which works only with `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` or
with package `auto-pst-pdf` and `lualatex` or `pdflatex` and option `shell-escape`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-grad, pst-text, auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\psset{fillstyle=gradient,gradbegin=red,gradend=cyan}
\pscharpath[gradangle=90]{\huge\bfseries TEST}% appears in black
\end{postscript}    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any chance to make it work with `luapstricks`?

Comment: yes, but not in the near future ...